# Problem with Loading and Preprocessing Data Using tf.Dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, dataset, prefetch

I'm trying to load `.npy files` using map method of `tf.Databases`. The reasoning behind this is, in the future, I will be loading data not only from `.npy` but also for `.dat` encoded in Medical Imaging format. I can do this with Keras Sequence class but I want to be able to prefetch my data since it will take a lot of time to load huge amounts of files from remote hard drives. Even if I'm loading them from the same hard drive it will take ages (seconds) to generate masks, load data, then feed it to network. Right now, I'm working with the most simple version of the problem that I can handle. I have been working on this for a couple of weeks (on and off for a year) to no avail. The code is given below and the error is.

> **TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Tensor**

I do know the reason behind the error but I could not convert it to something numpy can read. I can do this if it weren't an online operation, or output from dataset with list(file) then go for a for loop. I have researched it and every single book goes with the same irrelevant CSV example. I just need to load and preprocess data using prefetch method. So that when my network is doing reconstruction, I can fetch the next batch.

The file argument that is passed to the np_read function is a `tensor`. However, I expect it to be a `string`, this tensor has the string in it but I can not extract it.

> **Tensor("file:0", shape=(None,), dtype=string)**

When I convert `file` to `list` I get this error.

> **OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did not convert this function. Try decorating it directly with @tf.function.**

I expect to have a string that points to the location of the files, I do get these locations if I fetch the batch without mapping it. Then print using the `list` method.

> `array([b'C:\\Datasets\\MRI_Data\\Recon_v4\\Train\\e14080s3_P18944.7_144.npy', b'C:\\Datasets\\MRI_Data\\Recon_v4\\Train\\e13993s4_P16896.7_77.npy', b'C:\\Datasets\\MRI_Data\\Recon_v4\\Train\\e13992s4_P08704.7_65.npy'], dtype=object)>]`

Thank you kindly.

```
pattern = "C:/Datasets/MRI_Data/Recon_v4/Train/*.npy"
filepath_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern = pattern)

@tf.function
def np_read(file):
    loadedFile = np.load(file)
    return(loadedFile)

dataset = filepath_dataset.repeat(2).batch(3)
dataset = dataset.map(np_read)
```

Comment: So what is that `file` argument that gets passed to `np_read`?  Apparently you know what it should be (a file name or an already opened file).  But if you, or we, don't know what `dataset` is, or how its `map` method calls the function, we can't help you.

Comment: @hpaulj I have updated the question with the information you have mentioned.

Comment: Try using: dataset = pattern.repeat(2).batch(3)